# Http Post Request from Angular doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, angular, post, http-post

I am sending a post request this way(the baseURL is correct, the path /api/backend/valuePairs exists on the server).

```
 sendValues(valuepairList:{x:number;fx:number}[]): Observable<boolean> {
        const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

        console.log("sending to server: ",JSON.stringify(valuepairList)); //this seems ok too

        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/api/backend/valuePairs', {'data': JSON.stringify(valuepairList)}, options)
            .map(FunctionapproximationService.extractData)
            .catch(FunctionapproximationService.handleError);
}
```

But looking in Chrome at the website in Inspect mode / Networks nothing is sent during the execution of this function.(It is executed, the logging inside the function appears). Does someone has idea about what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You need to subscribe to `sendValues` call result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is sent because observables are lazy by default. You need to subscribe to them in order to invoke the HTTP request.

```
sendValues(args).subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```

The function passed to `subscribe` function will be called when the response arrives. It also accepts other functions for error handling and one that is called when the stream is completed, but I leave that to you to figure out from the documentation.

In RxJS worl, `.subscribe()` is basically like calling a usual JS function with parans: `()`. To execute a function, you need to call it. To execute an observable, you need to subscribe to it.